# switchMap to handle a list of observables in Angular

Tags: angular, http, observable

I'm working with angular, and I have a service called nameservice.ts like below:

```
getIds():Observable<Ids> {
return this.http.post(this.url,'').pipe(map(({ Ids }:any) => Ids.map(item=>({Id:item.Id})))) as Observable<Ids>;
}
getNames(data: Ids):Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http
        .post(url,data)
        .pipe(map(({ Names}: any) => Names.map(item => ({id: item.ID, name: item.name }))));
        }
```

In the component tablecomp.ts I call getIds() and then on each Id returned I call getNames.

```
getallNames(): any {
           this.nameservice.getIds().pipe(
                    switchMap((ids: Ids) => this.nameservice.getNames(ids))
            ).subscribe((response) => {
                    console.log(response)
            })
  }
```

What am I doing wrong here? The browser says ids in the switchMap() is not defined.

Comment: Fist check getIds values: this.nameservice.getIds().subscribe(console.log)

Comment: I dont see the console.log output and the browser breakpoint (Chrome and Firefox) on the line with console.log() is never hit. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add a tap and see what goes through the pipe

```
getallNames(): any {
           this.nameservice.getIds().pipe(
                    tap(ids => { console.log(ids); }),
                    switchMap((ids: Ids) => this.nameservice.getNames(ids))
            ).subscribe((response) => {
                    console.log(response)
            })
  }
```

Will tell you if the call to getIds returned undefined or not.